# Como fazer esse Regex no Delphi

Tags: delphi, regex

Estou tendo dificuldades para fazer a seguinte máscara.

Valores válidos:

```
1.98.212
1.98
1
```

O que eu consegui fazer até agora:

```
\d{0,1}(\.\d{0,2})?(\.\d{0,3})?
```

Está errado por que dá pra inserir 1.999, pois `(.\d{0,2})?` é opcional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, `{0,1}` significa "no mínimo zero e no máximo 1", o que quer dizer que o primeiro dígito também é opcional. Mas como ele parece ser obrigatório, então retire isso daí.

Já a segunda parte depois do ponto: ou ela tem 2 dígitos, ou tem os 2 dígitos e mais 3, então na verdade deve ficar assim:

```
^\d(\.\d{2}(\.\d{3})?)?$
```

Ou seja, depois dos 2 dígitos, opcionalmente pode ter 3 dígitos, mas todo esse trecho (2 dígitos mais 3 dígitos opcionais) também é opcional.

Troquei os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) pela quantidade exata. `{0,2}` significa "no mínimo zero e no máximo 2", ou seja, se tiver zero, um ou dois dígitos, serve. Já `{2}` significa "exatamente 2", que é o que você precisa.

O [ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), então para aceitar somente o caractere ponto, devemos escapá-lo com `\`.

Também usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` que indicam respectivamente o início e final da string, para garantir que não tenha nenhum caractere a mais.

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/zybIpK/1) a regex funcionando.

Comment: entendi.. entao eu tenho que deixar um agrupamento opcional e ir aninhando os outros..
valeu!